# dropDownList with array not working

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Can't get this to work for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <fx:Declarations>
<s:ArrayList id="mathChoices">
<fx:String>ADD</fx:String>
<fx:String>SUBTRACT</fx:String>
<fx:String>MULTIPLY</fx:String>
<fx:String>DIVIDE</fx:String>
 </s:ArrayList>

</fx:Declarations>
```

Then later:

```
<s:DropDownList id="math_selector" includeIn="Intro" x="49" y="241" dataProvider="mathChoices"
                prompt="Pick from..." requireSelection="true"></s:DropDownList>
```

it gives me this error:

> Initializer for 'dataProvider': values of type mx.collections.IList cannot be represented in 
>    text.

So what did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Edit your dataprovider as {mathChoices as IList}

   here is the code.

   <s:DropDownList id="math_selector"  x="49" y="241" 
   dataProvider="{mathChoices as IList}"                
   prompt="Pick from..." requireSelection="true">   
   </s:DropDownList>
```